# Why is $f_x(Ax + b) = f_x(x)$?

Tags: probability, expectation, density-function

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be random vector, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be a vector.

Now I should proof that the expected value is linear:

$$\mathbb{E}(Ax + b) = A \cdot \mathbb{E}(x) + b$$

The professor shared his proof. I understand every part of it, expcept for the first:

$$\mathbb{E}(Ax+b) = \int (Ax + b) f_x (x) \mathrm{d} x$$

Why is it not the following? Or is it the same?

$$\mathbb{E}(Ax+b) = \int (Ax + b) f_x (Ax + b) \mathrm{d} x$$

Comment: Look at the definition of $\Bbb E(g(X))$ when $X$ is a random variable with pdf $f_x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We only defined $\mathbb{E}(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} x \cdot f_x(x) \mathbb{d} x$ (by the way, I think here might be the problem: Is it important to write a capital $X$ / lower case $x$ sometimes? It is really hard to distinguish those in handwriting)

Comment: Ah, what you're missing is the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: Indeed the definition of the expectation is $$E(Ax+b)=\int uf_{Ax+b}(u)du$$ and it is a theorem that this equals $$\int(Au+b)f_x(u)du.$$ The usual approach to prove the theorem is to consider the set of functions $g$ such that $$\int g(u)f_{Ax+b}(u)du=\int g(Au+b)f_x(u)du$$ and to show that it contains the indicator functions, then the step functions, then every measurable positive function, and finally every function $g$ such that the integral converges.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Did: Nice! Thank you! Should I write a community wiki answer?

Comment: @MartinThoma by all means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Did, I confused some variables. The correct first step would have been

$$\mathbb{E}(Ax+b) = \int u f_{Ax+b} (u) \mathrm{d} u$$

Due to the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) (thank you Omnomnomnom) this is equal to

$$\int (Au+b) f_{x} (u) \mathrm{d} u$$